# Python: Converting a .txt containing binary data into a png

Tags: python, binary, png

I have a text file containing the binary data of a `png` (at least, I'm pretty sure it does, so I'm gonna go off of that assumption).

Anyways: I need to turn it back into a `png`.

I tried using the `binascii` library to do that, namely `unhexlify`, but I just get a `"this file is corrupted"` error when I try opening the image.

So what I'm asking: How do I put a `str` into a file such that I'll be able to see it as an image? Thanks

Comment: Please show us the beginning of the file at least. Does it start with `‰PNG`? With `89504E47`?

Comment: How would i go about turning the binary to that?

Comment: If your file is indeed binary, just rename it. If it's printable, include a sample of it in your question.

Comment: ok, so renaming the text to img.png just stores the same 0s and 1s in a png file. I need a way to convert those 0s and 1s to whichever format `‰PNG` would be in.

Comment: for reference: here's a bit of the file:

Comment: `100110000001100000100000000001011000100110000000000110000100110010000000010000010100001101111011101011011111110011010101101011111111011000111100011011110110010100100110100010111101010011110000000011111010111101001111011100110111111100111000100011110010101100000110100111010001111110111010111010001100111011101111000111010111101000111111110110100110111001000111111111110011001100101101010011010011111101001101111110111001111010110010111100111011010111110101111100001100011111101011110110100111111101111101111101110001010001011111111111011111101101111111110111111111`

Comment: just rename the file, or open the txt file and a png file, then read from the txt file and write to the png file. Simple file IO :)

Comment: What do you get if you process the text through: `struct.pack(str(len(text) // 8) + 'B', *[int(text[i:i+8],2) for i in range(0, len(text), 8)])`? That should split text 1s and 0s into groups of 8, convert them to integers, then pack them into a string read to be written to a file (in binary mode). It would be best to post the entire file so we can actually test an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your file consists of 1s and 0s in ascii, so `open("myfile.txt", "r").read()` returns `"100110000..."`

In that case the following should help:

```
with open("myfile.txt", "r") as f:
    txt = f.read()
b = "".join(chr(int(txt[i*8:(i+1)*8],2)) for i in range(len(txt) / 8))
with open("myfile.png", "wb") as f:
    f.write(b)
```

`unhexlify` is giving you trouble as it's trying to convert from hex, while the file is in binary.  You need the first 8 characters (`10011000`) to be converted to `"\x98"` but `unhexlify` will treat them as 4 pairs of hex numbers `10`, `01`, `10`, `00`, and will therefore convert to `'\x10\x01\x10\x00'`.

Having said that, when I run this on your file sample I don't get a result that looks like a PNG image.  According to PNG spec http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Structure.html the first byte of a PNG file is always 137, whereas the first byte of your file 10011000 = 0x98 = 152.

Comment: This isn't quite what I was looking for, but it's close enough. Especially the page you linked. Turns out I messed up somewhere higher up the chain.